# Unable to parse JSON values in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am facing some problem while parsing JSON values, Please find the JSON file below,

```
  {
       "Account": "xxx",
       "Account_desc": "xxx",
       "TimeZone": "GMT+05:30",
       "DeviceList": [
          {
             "Device": "xttt",
             "Device_desc": "txtx",
             "EventData": [
                {
                   "Device": "xttt",
                   "Timestamp": 1373539125,
                   "Timestamp_date": "2013/07/11",
                   "Timestamp_time": "16:08:45",
                   "StatusCode": 61715,
                   "StatusCode_hex": "0xF113",
                   "StatusCode_desc": "Stop",
                   "GPSPoint": "12.97887,77.51030",
                   "GPSPoint_lat": 12.97887,
                   "GPSPoint_lon": 77.51030,
                   "Speed": 0.0,
                   "Speed_units": "km/h",
                   "Odometer": 3.416,
                   "Odometer_units": "Km",
                   "Geozone": "zone4",
                   "Geozone_index": 0,
                   "Address": "cxcxc",
                   "DigitalInputMask": 251,
                   "DigitalInputMask_hex": "0xFB",
                   "Index": 0
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "Device": "pppp",
             "Device_desc": "statstr",
             "EventData": [
                {
                   "Device": "pppp",
                   "Timestamp": 1368870217,
                   "Timestamp_date": "2013/05/18",
                   "Timestamp_time": "15:13:37",
                   "StatusCode": 61715,
                   "StatusCode_hex": "0xF113",
                   "StatusCode_desc": "Stop",
                   "GPSPoint": "14.26281,80.11421",
                   "GPSPoint_lat": 14.26281,
                   "GPSPoint_lon": 80.11421,
                   "Speed": 0.0,
                   "Speed_units": "km/h",
                   "Odometer": 373.874,
                   "Odometer_units": "Km",
                   "Geozone": "port",
                   "Geozone_index": 0,
                   "Address": "asdfsdfss",
                   "Index": 0
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

From the above JSON , I would like to have only "GPSPoint_lat","GPSPoint_lon" and "Device" in "**EventData**" So I did the coding as follows,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = ApplicationContext.getHttpService()
                    .readAsJson(s);
            // System.out.println("indexvalue:"+s.indexOf(1,5));
            // JSONObject object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("DeviceList");
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DeviceList");

            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONArray secondarray = object.getJSONArray("EventData");

for (int i = 0; i < secondarray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Im...");
                    // System.out.println("Latitude:"+ ((JSONObject)
                    // jsonArray.get(i)).getString("GPSPoint_lat"));
                    // String id = ((JSONObject)
                    // jsonArray.get(i)).getString("deviceID");
                    // arr = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);
                    JSONObject obj = secondarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String lat = obj.getString("GPSPoint_lat");
                    String lon = obj.getString("GPSPoint_lon");

........//..
...///......}}
```

But problem in the above code is whenever I am executing I am getting the arraylength is 1, i.e., getting only one value I mean first Eventdata values. What i need in this is I would like to get all the "Eventdata" values. Please suggest me regarding this.

Regards
Priya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DeviceList");

for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

            JSONArray secondarray = object.getJSONArray("EventData");

for (int i = 0; i < secondarray.length(); i++) {

                    System.out.println("Im...");
                    // System.out.println("Latitude:"+ ((JSONObject)
                    // jsonArray.get(i)).getString("GPSPoint_lat"));
                    // String id = ((JSONObject)
                    // jsonArray.get(i)).getString("deviceID");
                    // arr = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);
                    JSONObject obj = secondarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String lat = obj.getString("GPSPoint_lat");
                    String lon = obj.getString("GPSPoint_lon");


}
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much ...you are rocking

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

I am guessing at this point in the above code you are just fetching the data at the first index which is specified by '0'. Hence you get the length also as one. Try doing the **object.getJSONArray()** inside the loop with the index. Maybe that will help you get all the data inside "EventData". Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For JSON parsing use following class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONParser {

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    JSONObject jObj;
    String json;
    InputStream is = null;

    public JSONObject getJsonFromUrl(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("Json String : " + json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

and in your MainActivity use following code to parse it.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject o = parser.getJsonFromUrl("yourjsonurl");

String Account = o.getString("Account");
String Account_desc = o.getString("Account_desc");

JSONArray array = o.getJSONArray("DeviceList");
JSONObject o1 = array.getJSONObject(0);
String Device = o1.getString("Device");

//Again you have JSONArray
JSONArray a = o1.getJSONArray("EventData");

//Then get object form array at index 0.

JSONObject obj = a.getJSONObject(0);
```

Then get your data from this json object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your JSON is that in eventData array you have 1 JSON object with alot of mappings and not allot of jsonObjects. If you wannt EventData to be a JSONArray with all

```
.."Geozone": "zone4",
                   "Geozone_index": 0,
                   "Address": "cxcxc",
                   "DigitalInputMask": 251,
                   "DigitalInputMask_hex": "0xFB",
                   "Index": 0...
```

as JsonObject you need yo change the JSON to be as an array

```
..{"Geozone": "zone4"},
                   {"Geozone_index": 0},
                   {"Address": "cxcxc"},
                   {"DigitalInputMask": 251},
                   {"DigitalInputMask_hex": "0xFB"},
                  { "Index": 0}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONArray DeviceListArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DeviceList");


for (int i = 0; i < DeviceListArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject Deviceobject = DeviceListArray.getJSONObject(i);


            JSONArray EventDataArray = Deviceobject.getJSONArray("EventData");

for (int j= 0; j < EventDataArray.length(); j++) {


                    JSONObject valueObj = EventDataArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    String GPSPoint_lat = valueObj.getString("GPSPoint_lat");
                    String GPSPoint_lon = valueObj.getString("GPSPoint_lon");
                    String Device = valueObj.getString("Device");
     // Store this three values in ArrayList
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Priya, Your json contains three objects and two arrays as follows

Objects
 1. Entire response
 2. DeviceList
 3. EventData

Arrays

1. Device List - holds arrays of devices
2. Event Data - Arrays of events

Now carefully look your JSON, that json contains N number of Devices but every device has one event, So you have to iterate DeviceList and then iterate event list.

So that iteration should as follows.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = ApplicationContext.getHttpService().readAsJson(s);

JSONArray jsonDeviceListArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DeviceList");
int deviceCount = jsonDeviceListArray.length();

JSONObject jsonDeviceObj;
JSONArray jsonEventList;
for (int deviceIndex = 0; deviceIndex < deviceCount; deviceIndex++) {
    jsonDeviceObj = jsonDeviceListArray.getJSONObject(deviceIndex);
    //Here you can print device, device_desc from jsonDeviceObj

    jsonEventList = jsonDeviceObj.getJSONArray("EventData");
    int eventCount = jsonEventList.length();

    JSONObject jsonEventObj;
    for (int eventIndex = 0; eventIndex < eventCount; eventIndex++) {
        jsonEventObj = jsonEventList.getJSONObject(eventIndex);
        //Here you can print event info.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have missing "" in your json data. All numbers should have "", as before parsing it is treated as string.

Comment: Hi bro ..I have just posted a part of JSON..so dont worry about that.